# Visual Basic File debugs properly, but will not run in Windows

Tags: vb.net

I have a very basic Visual Basic Program that I created in Visual Studio 2010.  It's a form application where clicking a button runs a simple calculation and then outputs the answer with MsgBox.  When, I debug it works properly, however when I successfully build and run the exe, nothing happens.  What could be going on here?

Comment: Have you checked the task manager to see if it is an active process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing anything like this?

```
Debug.Print(MsgBox("Your answer is 7.  Try again?", vbYesNo))
```

In other words, are you making use of a library that is only available to a debugging session (in this case, System.Diagnostics).

Comment: Nope, just `MsgBox("Your answer is 7.  Try again?", vbYesNo)`